# loading files list file for package 'linux-modules-5.11.0-25-generic

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.4.0-81-generic.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
loading files list file for package 'linux-modules-5.11.0-25-generic': cannot read /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-modules-5.11.0-25-generic.list (In
put/output error)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

## Hello Ubuntu team....

I need Your Support To Fix This Issue...Any One From Team ..please give me solution .
i face this issue most of time....
please help as soon as possible
Thanks

Comment: I/O error there means that either the package is corrupt and your downloaded copy is broken, or your disk is dying.  Do you get I/O errors anywhere else?

Comment: First Thanks Sir For Reply!......Sir I Get this Error when try to install new software...as currently i try to install ROS .(so i find this Error)..Early days i also try to install VScode...i get this error,,,,but i reinstall (through USB)...and then VCcode insall correctly...bu now  this problem shown again...please sir support me to ressolve this issue..Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest validating your drive health - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  (GUI tools can be used too; you haven't provided OS & release, which I could guess but it's best if we're not guessing)